# Find the probability distribution function of $Y_(n)$ = max($Y_1, Y_2, . . . , Y_n$).

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Y_1, Y_2, . . . , Y_n$ be independent random variables, each with a beta distribution, with $α = β = 2$. Find
a. the probability distribution function of $Y_(n)$ = max($Y_1, Y_2, . . . , Y_n$).

Could anyone help get me started on this?

Comment: Hint: The event $\{\max_i Y_i \leq \alpha\}$ occurs if and only if $\cap_{i=1}^n \{Y_i \leq \alpha\]$ occurs.

Comment: Please use `Y_{(n)}`, not `Y_(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For i.i.d variables, $P(X_{(n)}<t)=(P(X<t))^{n}$.

Comment: So, we can integrate f(y) for beta distribtion when $ α=β=2$ and raise it to the power of n?

Comment: Yes you can; but I should ask: What does this imply for the pdf of $X_{(n)}$?

Comment: we can find $f_u (t) = n[F_y(t)] ^{n-1} f_y(t) $ right?

Comment: Yes. Now you on the right track.

Comment: let $U = Y_{(n)}$ Is $F_u (t) = [3y^2 - 2y^3]^n$?

Comment: Sorry but I have to sleep now. Good luck!